# Function multiple arguments dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe with a lot of dates. I want to apply a function with multiple arguments to a set of those columns in order to create a new one in this dataframe.

The function I have is the following (it works correctly):

```
def func(*args):
count=0
for i in args:
    if i=="Cool":
        count+=1
return count
```

I create a new column in my dataframe applying this function to a set of columns:

```
dates=["2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2009",]
df["new_Column"]=df.apply(lambda row : func(row[date] for date in dates), axis = 1)
```

However, after execution my new_Column is constantly equal to zero. The problem comes from the last line for sure. Any ideas?

Comment: May you provide a sample of your original dataframe to work with, and an expected output?

Comment: First of all these are years, not dates, so I'd pay attention to the naming of your variables, especially if there may be actual dates later on that are being compared to these years. Second, are strings designating years the index of your dataframe, that is, does df["2000"] give you a dataframe record? Give an example snippet of your dataframe, including the index, and we can start helping you.

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you would explain what are you going to achieve by that function... I.e. what would you want to have in the "new_Column" column?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're passing generator object as only argument to `func`. Since generator object is not `'Cool'` you get `0`.

As others noticed your question is not complete. But as far as I can anticipate you have dataframe which looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'2000': ['Cool', 'yay', 'nope'], '2001': ['ugly', 'cool', 'nice']})
```

So you can rewrite your `func`

```
def func(lst):
    count=0
    for i in lst:
        if i=="Cool":
            count+=1
    return count
```

And create new column with `list` constructor

```
df["new_Column"]=df.apply(lambda row : func(list(row[date] for date in ['2000', '2001'])), axis = 1)
```

and receive

```
    2000    2001    new_Column
0   Cool    ugly    1
1   yay     cool    0
2   nope    nice    0
```

If this is the case there is pure pandas solution

```
df['new_Column2']=df[df.isin(['Cool'])].count(axis=1)
```